# serialize() form returns empty string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form:

```
<form id="filess" style="padding-left:30px">
    @foreach(Element elem in Model.Elements)
    {
        @Html.Label(elem.Name + ":  ") 
        <input type="file" name="@elem.Name"/>
        <br />
    }
    <br />
</form>
```

And my javascript:

```
var form = $("#filess");
form.serialize();//returns empty string
```

Why am I getting empty string? I have names to my input elements so what is wrong here?

Comment: file inputs cannot be serialised to a string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks. I've been trying all day to upload a file async but couldn't; all methods found failed. Do you happen to know one that works in MVC?

Comment: Yep, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously